# Geoserver WFS coordinates reprojection returns wrong latitude

Tags: leaflet, geoserver, coordinate-systems, reprojection-error

I'm using geoserver and leaflet to show some data in an application.

The geoserver connect to a DB which contains spatial data (points) in `EPSG:3785` format.

Leaflet require `EPSG:4326` format to show data so I'm getting geojson reference of this data asking the geoserver to reproject the coordinates from `EPSG:3785` to `EPSG:4326` using WFS param `srsName`. The problem is, while longitude is reprojected correctly latitude is not.

Fore example one of my points has this coordinates: `1078019.71674498 ; 5630250.19147139`

Using [CS2CS](https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/) to convert them the result is `9.68401588134 ; 45.0554183303` (which are correct when showed on the map), while the geoserver returns `9.68401588 ; 45.24751598`, way far from the position they should represent (rougthly 30km north).

I cannot understand why is just the longitude that is wrong neither what should I do to prevent this from happening, aside from asking data in the correct format.

Does anyone happen to had the same problem? Looking in the internet I couldn't find anything that could help me.

I tried to convert data in the layer definition but it was useless, the problem persist.

Comment: Are you really sure that your input data is really in 3857? That would be unusual for any real world data

Comment: 3785 is deprecated. Use [3857 instead because they are essentially identical. The datums and projections are different, but they are mathematically equivalent.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141175/is-geotools-transformation-of-epsg3785-web-mercator-to-epsg4326-wrong#comment204515_141175)

Comment: @IanTurton unfortunatly italian data are often provided in this format, but thos are old, maybe they were updated recently (but I don't think so).

Comment: @LucasP.Luiz I tried what you proposed and it worked! Thak you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone would face this problem in future here is the solution:

as LucasP.Luiz commented, it is simple as setting `Declared SRS` in layer definition to EPSG:3857 ([see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klaf6.png)), then the projection works as intended.